How the GPIO works internally?
I have a fair understanding about how to configure as input/output enable pull-up etc. While going through the datasheet of ATTiny85 Section 10.2 (The same diagram also there in ATmega328p) I have seen the following diagram which explain how the GPIO is working.

By looking this diagram, I am a bit confused when the system bus is connected to an AND gate and another input (WPx) is also connected the same AND gate. I know what the purpose of different logical gates and flip-flops is. But I confused, Specifically, under what conditions would the system bus provide a high signal? I am seeking an overall explanation of this diagram in hopes that it will help me better comprehend the GPIO functionalities of other microcontrollers as well.

shafeeq - Hi, Please edit the question and add the specific datasheet name & its link, for the image you copied into the question. This is a requirement to comply with the site rule on referencing. TY

Take a look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKQMCwCtVrs and here https://deepbluembedded.com/arduino-port-manipulation-registers-example/  Any additional questions?

Consider "port B". On the ATmega328p, this consists of 8 I/O pins PB7 to PB0. On the ATtiny85, it's the 6 I/O pins PB5 to PB0.
At the "software level", these are controlled by three registers that can be written or read via I/O instructions. The registers are PORTB ("Port B Data Register"), DDRB ("Port B Data Direction Register"), and PINB ("Port B Input Pins Address").
At the "hardware level" as represented by the schematic, when PORTB is written, the 8 bits written to that port are placed on the "Data Bus", and then the "WRB" signal (i.e., WRx with x=B) is strobed high.  (Note that "WRB" is a single signal, shared by all pins in PORTB.  The eight bits written to the port are placed on 8 lines of the data bus, and the single signal "WRB" is strobed high to represent the fact that this was a write to PORTB.)  When PORTB is read, the "RRB" signal is strobed high, and whatever the hardware places on the data bus is returned by the read operation.
The other signals "WDB", "RDB", "WPB", and "RPB" are similarly strobed high when the other two registers are read and written.
In this schematic, any arrows to and from the "Data Bus" represent the signal line of the bus associated with the relevant pin "n".
So, for example, if you perform the operations:
 out PORTB,6
 out DDRB,3
 out PINB,15

The first two operations will:

Set lines 1 and 2 on the data bus to high, all other lines low and strobe the WRB line high. Via the OR gate, this will clock the PORTBn flip-flops which will store the MUX output for all bits. Because the selection lines for the MUXes are low (the AND gate output is low because WPB has not been strobed), the MUX output will just be a copy of the data bus. The effect is that the PORTBn flip flops will be set high for lines 1 and 2 and low for all other lines.
Set lines 0 and 1 on the data bus to high, all other lines low and strobe the WDB line high.  This will have the effect of storing these bit values in the DDBn flip-flops in the top right, since they are all clocked by the WDB line.

(The result, after the first two instructions, is that for port 0 where DDB0 has output high and PORTB0 has output low, the output buffer will be enabled to place a low signal on pin PB0. For port 1, where DDB0 has output high and PORTB0 has output low, the output buffer will be enabled to place a high signal on pin PB1. For port 2, where DDB0 has output low and PORTB0 has output high, the output buffer is disabled, but the pullup resistor is enabled, so PB0 is configured as an input with pullup.  The remaining pins are configured as inputs without pullup.)
The third operation sets lines 0-3 on the data bus to high, all other lines low, and strobes WPB. Via the AND gate, the MUXes for lines 0-3 have their selection line high, selecting the output of the inverter, while the MUXes for the remaining lines select the data bus (which is low for these lines).  Via the OR gate, the PORTBn flip-flops are clocked but only for lines 0-3. The result is that PORTB0 to PORTB3 are toggled (because they store the inverse of their previous values via the MUXes) while PORTB4 to PORTB7 (or PORTB5, for the ATtiny85) are unchanged because the flip-flops aren't clocked.
(The result is that pin PB0 outputs high (where before it was low), pin PB1 outputs low (where before it was high), pin PB2 is still configured for read but with the pullup disabled (where before it was enabled), and pin PB3 is configured for read with the pullup enabled (where before it was disabled). The remaining pins are unchanged -- they are still configured as inputs without pullup.)

As a background, writing the PINx register toggles the IO pins you selected.
And the system bus provides the bit of the data you write when writing to PINx register. Just like it does when you write to PORTx or DDRx registers.
It simply means when you write to PINx register a data byte, the WPx strobes high, all the bits that are high will cause the AND output to pass the WPx pulse through WRx gate to the PORTxn flip-flop to toggle state by loading the current value inverted with the inverter through the mux.
And all the bits in the byte that was written low, nothing happens as the WPx pulse is masked by the written data bit being low.
So in short, the output register state is toggled only when data bit is 1 AND when writing to PINx register.
